# perl regex - catching four numbers separated by space

Tags: regex, perl

I know that we can use regex in perl to catch numbers using `[\d]`, but my pattern is like this:

```
261 193 546 302
```

or it could be like this:

```
16 0 98 120
```

The point is - I just want to catch a line that has any four numbers separated by a space. Each number can be made up of any number of digits, it could be a single-digit number, or a double-digit number, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^\d+(?:\s+\d+){3}$
```

Try this.This should do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You don't explicitly have to wrap the token inside of a character class. And for this you want to assert the start of the string and end of the string positions, so I would use anchors and quantify a non-capturing group "3" times.

```
^\d+(?: \d+){3}$
```

Explanation:

```
^         # the beginning of the string
\d+       # digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
(?:       # group, but do not capture (3 times):
          #   ' '
  \d+     #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
){3}      # end of grouping
$         # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: Don't forget to use a `\ ` or `[ ]` for that space.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirements to "*catch a line that has any four numbers separated by a space*". I would use the following as it contains a capture group which will contain your number sequence and will ignore any leading or tailing spaces.

```
((?:\d+\s){3}\d+)
```

**[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/dV4oV4/2)**

**Usage in Perl**

```
$re = "/((?:\\d+\\s){3}\\d+)/";
```

As you can see it will match exactly **4** numbers separated by a single space and will ignore preceding and trailing characters.

***Alternate***

If you where being explicit and actually want to capture the *whole* line including any other characters this will be better suited.

```
(^.*(?:\d+\s){3}\d+.*$)
```

**[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/dV4oV4/3)**

**Usage In Perl**

```
$re = "/(^.*(?:\\d+\\s){3}\\d+.*$)/mx";
```

Note this will match numbers with decimal places due to the way it is structured.

Answer (score 1):

Try `^\d+\s\d+\s\d+\s\d+$`. That will match 4 numbers with spaces and nothing else.

[Sample](https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/)

Comment: @smerny You're right, it should be \d+. Ill fix in a sec

Comment: While you are at it use \s+ as well. More reliable.